# android sdk how to keep TextView centered with dynamic set of text sizes

Tags: android

I have exhausted my search to keep the TextView centered, when changing the textsize.

There are many similar questions on this site, but none of the threads provide a solution for my problem.

In my XML file, I have a RelativeLayout, and TextView inside of it(code below).

When changing the text size from 1 --> 300 of the TextView, and then back from 300 --> 1 programmatically, the position of the TextView changes and shifts lower towards the bottom of the screen.

How do i keep the TextView centered with a dynamic set of textsizes??

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/vgRelativeLayout">

    <TextView            
        android:id="@+id/tViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_gravity="center"  
        android:center_vertical="true"
        android:center_horizontal="true" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you do the following programmatically, the position of the TextView will change from the original centered position set by center_vertical and center_horizontal properties.

The new position of the TextView will be shifted lower on the vertical scale.

The position on the horizontal scale does not change.

```
 TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewID);  

 tView.setTextSize(1);
 Thread.sleep(5000);

 tView.setTextSize(300);
 Thread.sleep(5000);

 tview.setTextSize(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to call the layout to re-do it's layout. In this case you usually use RequestLayout() which can be called by getting a reference to the RelativeLayout.

So you'd need to give the RelativeLayout an Id, then get the reference by findViewById(), and then call RequestLayout once you've changed the text size.

Comment: When i assign an id to RelativeLayout and then try to find it with findViewById(), i get the following error: 'vgRelativeLayout cannot be resolved or is not a field'.

Comment: code:
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vgRelativeLayout);

Comment: Sounds like it isn't being compiled into the generated R file properly. What's your new xml code?

Comment: ok I made a mistake, i needed for the id to have (+) infront of it: android:id="@+id/vgRelativeLayout"

Comment: I did what you have recommended: getting RelativeLayout by Id and running RequestLayout() everytime the textsize changes, and this still does not bring the TextView back to the center vertically

Comment: Can i ask the reason that you put the textsize to 1 rather than just hide it? It seems that making it invisible would be an easier solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  & android:layout_centerVertical="true" or try this android:layout_centerInParent="true". If it works click up for vote me